# Adding multiple white noise from different sources

Tags: noise

If we add two white noise together would the result amplitude or sound pressure level of the sum be different than when we add sine waves of the same amplitude and sound pressure level?

Comment: I believe the noise *power* adds rather than the amplitude. That's because sometimes the noise cancels out and sometimes it adds up

Comment: For describing noise, we do not talk about amplitude normally because depending on the time duration of observation, the peak voltage could keep increasing. We talk about noise power and vrms when it comes to noise. So, I am confused what you are looking for. Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: @sai I edit my question so it's clear

Comment: @parvin Please ask a new question instead of changing the meaning since the question already has answers. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As with all signals whether periodc or not, the instantaneous values are combined using addition.

However, amplitudes(rms values) are combined as the square root of the sum of the squares.$$v_{\text{total}}=\sqrt{v^2_{dc}+v^2_{ac}+v^2_{noise}}$$

Comment: The noise sources need to have been measured with the same bandwidth though (for the RMS summation).